# Reaction Bot DM discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about having a discord bot in python send a dm to a user when the user reacts to a message with a checkmark. Like, let's say I have my bot in python send a message and when the user reacts to it it will send a dm to that user with info.

[image: Example image]

This is the code I was able to build which I guess is how it would work obviously it's not python syntax. Thanks!

```
if user.reaction == ✅:

    member.send("Nice to know you checked the message thanks")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) or the [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add). The latter is better since it does not rely on the bot's message cache

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.emoji == "\u2705" and reaction.message_id == 123:
        await payload.member.send("Hey")
```

This uses the raw event because the normal event only works if the message is in the bot's cache, which requires the message to be sent after the bot starts. \u2705 is the code of the ✅, you can also just use ✅ instead. 123 is just an example message-id, you can change it to anything you want. payload.member may be None under some circumstances so you also may wanna check for that

Comment: where would I put the like message like if its a specific message id they react to how would i add that. @Wasi Master

Comment: @Secretcode you didn't say that in the question... you can add a `and payload.message_id == 123:` at the end of the if statement or add another if statement with `if payload.message_id == 123:`. See the docs for more info

Comment: I want to make sure this is 100% right and im sorry if this comes out rude but would you mind adding that code to your updated answer. One so its easy for me to put together. Two so if other people have questions on it they can see it

Comment: @Secretcode Do you want to dm **only** when the reaction is on a specific message, or do you want some other message to be sent if the reaction is on that specific message?

Comment: DM only would be awesome

Comment: @Secretcode okay I edited it